# UEFI function GetVariable() returns EFI_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c, boot, uefi

I am trying to create a UEFI driver that will simply read a bunch of variables, and based on the values it will show some output to the screen.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <efi.h>
#include <efilib.h>
#include <memory.h>

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
efi_main (EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable) {
   InitializeLib(ImageHandle, SystemTable);
   Print(L"Hello, world!\n");

   EFI_GUID guid = EFI_GLOBAL_VARIABLE;
   UINT32 attr = 0;
   UINTN data_size = 0;
   void* data = NULL;

   EFI_STATUS status =
        SystemTable->RuntimeServices->GetVariable(L"Boot0001", &guid, &attr, &data_size, data);

   if(status != EFI_SUCCESS)
   {
       Print(L"GetVariable() failed!\n");
       return status;
   }

   Print(L"Success!\n");

   return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

The issue is that the code above returns the error value of `EFI_NOT_FOUND`, which indicates that the variable does not exist. If I dump all variables though using `dmpstore –all -b`, I can clearly see it there:

```
Variable NV+RT+BS 'EFIGlobalVariable:Boot0001' DataSize = 0x21
  00000000: 03 00 00 00 0D 00 20 00-55 00 53 00 42 00 00 00  *...... .U.S.B...*
  00000010: 05 01 09 00 11 00 00 00-00 7F FF 04 00 00 00 42  *...............B*
  00000020: 4F                                               *O*
```

Which begs the question now, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it `EFI_GLOBAL_VARIABLE` or `EFI_GLOBAL_VARIABLE_GUID` ?

Comment: @MichaelPetch And that is, humans, ladies and gentlemen, why C APIs should be viewed with suspicion at least, but typically with outright revulsion. This "everything is an int, no really" is pure madnes. Give me an `enum class` anytime.

Comment: @MichaelPetch very good observation. In this case it is the same. `EFI_GLOBAL_VARIABLE_GUID` seems to be undefined to me, but looking at several source code definitions online, the `GUID` value is actually the same in both scenarios. No idea when or why this name change occured. If you are still in doubt, I could provide you with my sources.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica it is really madness. Almost every time I deal with low-level APIs I end up doing silly mistakes that stem from weird and unnecessary type definitions that are based on data-types that (I believe) should never have been used in the first place.